# For Not Working and Not Adding Value to contador_NA Variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I got a array, and I want to now how many strings `NA` are in there. So I made a for loop to add `1` to the variable `contador_NA` every time it finds a `NA`

The variable `contador_NA` always returns `0`.

```
var contador_NA = 0

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    if (['imoveis'][i]['VALOR_CORRIGIDO_VENDA'] = "NA")
    {    
        contador_NA++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details as to what you are attempting to accomplish here?

Comment: I got a array, and i want to now how many strings "NA" are in there. So i made a for loop to add 1 to the variable contador_NA every time it finds a "NA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. For comparison you should be using the `==` operator in your if-statement. You could also look at using the `===` operator if you want to compare the datatype.

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp for some examples usages of comparison operators.

Furthermore, the variable you are trying to compare with is not being access correctly. There is no variable name prior to the first braces `[]`.

Comment: still not counting... i think theres is something about async programing.... it always prints contador_NA = 0

Comment: Look at the comparison variable `['imoveis'][i]['VALOR_CORRIGIDO_VENDA']`. There is no variable name. I.e. access it like `my_var['imoveis'][i]['VALOR_CORRIGIDO_VENDA']` or perhaps you meant `imoveis[i]['VALOR_CORRIGIDO_VENDA']`?